# Twitter Bootstrap 3: Spyscroll always select last and working in JSFIDDLE not local with same code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is a little funny that same code doesn't produce the same behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/5n3ygvhe/

This is the jsfiddle code.
It is a good demo of spyscroll.

So I copy the codes into my local html file.

Here is my local html file. I am holding the file with appengine. I have checked that jquery, bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js is loaded correctly. And the version of jquery is 2.1.3 and bootstrap is 3.0.0.

I have tried other jsfiddle for spyscroll, exact same thing happens. Not working on local but working in jsfiddle.
When I scroll the page, the nav li doesn't reflect that and always stick to the last item.

```
<html>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
<!-- <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.group {
    background: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
}
.group .subgroup {
    background: orange;
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
}
#sidebar.affix {
    top: 20px;
}
/* sidebar */
.bs-docs-sidebar {
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* all links */
.bs-docs-sidebar .nav>li>a {
    color: #999;
    border-left: 2px solid transparent;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

/* nested links */
.bs-docs-sidebar .nav .nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

/* active & hover links */
.bs-docs-sidebar .nav>.active>a, 
.bs-docs-sidebar .nav>li>a:hover, 
.bs-docs-sidebar .nav>li>a:focus {
    color: #563d7c;                 
    text-decoration: none;          
    background-color: transparent;  
    border-left-color: #563d7c; 
}
/* all active links */
.bs-docs-sidebar .nav>.active>a, 
.bs-docs-sidebar .nav>.active:hover>a,
.bs-docs-sidebar .nav>.active:focus>a {
    font-weight: 700;
}
/* nested active links */
.bs-docs-sidebar .nav .nav>.active>a, 
.bs-docs-sidebar .nav .nav>.active:hover>a,
.bs-docs-sidebar .nav .nav>.active:focus>a {
    font-weight: 500;
}

/* hide inactive nested list */
.bs-docs-sidebar .nav ul.nav {
    display: none;           
}
/* show active nested list */
.bs-docs-sidebar .nav>.active>ul.nav {
    display: block;           
}

</style>
<!-- Top Navbar -->
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                Bootstrap 3.0 Skeleton
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <!--Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="col-xs-3 bs-docs-sidebar">
        <ul id="sidebar" class="nav nav-stacked">
            <li>
                <a href="#GroupA">Group A</a>
                <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                    <li><a href="#GroupASub1">Sub-Group 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#GroupASub2">Sub-Group 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#GroupB">Group B</a>
                <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                    <li><a href="#GroupBSub1">Sub-Group 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#GroupBSub2">Sub-Group 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#GroupC">Group C</a>
                <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                    <li><a href="#GroupCSub1">Sub-Group 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#GroupCSub2">Sub-Group 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--Main Content -->
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <section id="GroupA" class="group">
            <h3>Group A</h3>
            <div id="GroupASub1" class="subgroup">
                <h4>Group A Sub 1</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="GroupASub2" class="subgroup">
                <h4>Group A Sub 2</h4>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="GroupB" class="group">
            <h3>Group B</h3>
            <div id="GroupBSub1" class="subgroup">
                <h4>Group B Sub 1</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="GroupBSub2" class="subgroup">
                <h4>Group B Sub 2</h4>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="GroupC" class="group">
            <h3>Group C</h3>
            <div id="GroupCSub1" class="subgroup">
                <h4>Group C Sub 1</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="GroupCSub2" class="subgroup">
                <h4>Group C Sub 2</h4>
            </div>
        </section>    
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.bs-docs-sidebar',
    offset: 40
});
$("#sidebar").affix({
    offset: {
      top: 60
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` on top of page.

And use `$(function() {}` wrapper for jQuery

Comment: Add <!DOCTYPE html> solves the problem. No need to use $(function(){} wrapper.     Thanks for the solution.